# html - div on the centr

Tags: html, center

how can i set div position at the center of the page with size, for example, 80%/80%.

**UPD:** margin: 0 auto; works, but only for horizontal alignment. And i also need vertical.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [page](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/) talks about some different ways to achieve vertical centering using css. I've used method 2 before with success but I consider all of these a hack at best.

Answer (score 1):

Set a fixed width and auto-margins.

```
<style type="text/css">
#center {
  width:300px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="center"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I know this. I wanna do that not only for sides... But for top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want, but it is not pretty.

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto;width:80%;height:80%;">
This will probably not work for you however because you did not provide code
</div>
```